# Chern classes of PU(n)-bundles

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces, chern-classes

Let $PU(n) = U(n)/U(1)$ be the projective unitary group and denote by $BPU(n)$ its classifying space. Consider the algebra $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ as an $n^2$-dimensional Hilbert space equipped with the inner product $\langle T, S \rangle = \mathrm{tr}(T^*S)$. Then we have a group homomorphism
$$
PU(n) \to U(n^2)\ ,
$$
which sends $[u] \in PU(n)$ to the linear map $\mathrm{Ad}_u \colon M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to M_n(\mathbb{C}) \ ;\ T \mapsto uTu^*$. The corresponding map $BPU(n) \to BU(n^2)$ on classifying spaces induces 
$$
\mathrm{Ad}^* \colon \mathbb{Z}[c_1, \dots, c_{n^2}] \cong H^*(BU(n^2), \mathbb{Z}) \to H^*(BPU(n), \mathbb{Z})\ .
$$
The generators of the polynomial ring are the Chern classes of the universal bundle. Since every bundle of matrix algebras has the unit section as a non-vanishing section, we have $\mathrm{Ad}^*(c_{n^2}) = 0$.

> > For which $n \in \mathbb{N}$ do we have $\mathrm{Ad}^*(c_{n^2-1}) \neq 0$ ?

(I just realized that the map could rightfully be called $\mathrm{BAd}^*$, but decided against it :-)

Answer (score 3):

You may as well look at what happens on maximal tori, since Chern classes are seen there. Let $T$ be the maximal torus of $PU(n)$ and $D$ the maximal torus of the unitary group. Let's write the cohomology rings of their classifying spaces as $\mathbb{Z}[t_i-t_j]/~$ and $Z[x_{i,j}]$ resp. Here the quotient is by the evident linear relations on the generators (you get a polynomial ring in $n-1$ generators I just wanted to avoid choosing a basis).

It's not hard to check that the induced map on cohomology sends $x_{i,j}$ to $t_i-t_j$. (In particular the diagonal guys go to zero). So the effect on Chern classes is the effect on symmetric polynomials- you're asking when those go to zero in the target.

You've observed that the top polynomial vanishes, which here follows from the fact that the top symmetric polynomial has a factor of, say, $x_{1,1}$ in it.

Unless I'm mistaken- none of the other terms vanish. You can see this by noting that the total Chern class is given by coefficients of the polynomial in $z$, $\prod (z-t_i - t_j)$. Substitute $t_1=1$ and $t_i=0$ otherwise. The resulting polynomial is like $z(z-1)^k$ which has vanishing constant term but non vanishing coefficients otherwise (binomial coefficients).

Comment: (To compute the map on cohomology you need to know that inversion on the circle gives multiplication by -1 on group cohomology and multiplication sends a generator to the sum of the two natural generators, since the Chern class of a tensor product is the sum.)

Comment: How do these classes behave under $\mathrm{Ad}^*$?

Comment: What do you mean? Ad* takes x_ij to t_i-t_j and Chern classes go to the corresponding symmetric polynomials.

Comment: There is one thing I don't understand though. What is wrong with the following reasoning: The $(n^2-1)$th Chern class in $H^*(BU(n^2), \mathbb{Z})$ is mapped to the $(n^2-1)$th elementary symmetric polynomial. This is a sum of monomials with each one containing at least one "diagonal" element $x_{ii}$. Since the induced map $H^*(BU(n^2)) \to H^*(BPU(n))$ is a ring homomorphism, this should be mapped to $0$ by your argument.

Comment: It's not the case that each monomial has such an element. For example, the *first* symmetric polynomial is just the sum of all the $x_{i,j}$. Most of those will map to something nonzero.

Comment: Indeed, every symmetric polynomial *except* the last one has at least some monomial that doesn't contain one of these diagonal elements! (Which is essentially the content of the last paragraph).

Comment: @DylanWilson Isn't the second to last one (i.e. the $(n^2 - 1)$th one) the sum over all the monomials, which are products of all $x_{i,j}$, where I leave out one of them (e.g. $x_{11}x_{12}x_{21} + x_{11}x_{21}x_{22} + x_{11}x_{12}x_{22} + x_{12}x_{21}x_{22}$ for $n = 2$)? If this is true, then every such monomial will contain a diagonal element.

Comment: Ah- apologies, I guess I spoke too quickly. So then I guess something like first $n^2-n$ will be nonzero and the rest will be zero?

Comment: @DylanWilson Can you modify your answer accordingly? Then I can accept it. Thanks!